# IBM DB2 - Query optimization

Tags: database, optimization, db2, db2-zos

**Problem**

I have a table and I need to make a selection using the following rules,

1. **AUFT_LOESCH_KZ** can't be null
2. **AUFT_AUFT_ART** has to be E
3. **AUFT_FZG_ART** can be 0,1,2,E,F or G
4. If **AUFT_PAT(date)** Year is the same as the current year then I want to select all the previous months than the one we are currently in for the current year

**Example**

If **AUFT_PAT** year holds 2018 and the current year is 2018 then I want to select all the previous months based on **MONTH(AUFT_PAT)** until 2018 January

The following query works, but it's taking too much CPU time on the mainframe, like 50 minutes and it wasn't even close to finishing

Each **DBIN0XX** has approximately 20.000 registers.

I'm pretty new to the DB2 scenario so I don't have a good perspective on how to optimize it or how to separate the query, any help would be deeply appreciated as it would directly impact my development.

```
DATEI01 SEL DBHOLDER  AUFT_LOESCH_KZ IS NULL                                                         
                      AND AUFT_AUFT_ART IN ('E')                                                     
                      AND AUFT_FZG_ART IN ('0', '1', '2', 'E', 'F', 'G')                             
                      AND                                                                            
                        (                                                                            
                              AUFT_PAT <                                                             
                              (                                                                      
                               SELECT                                                                
                                 MIN(KALW_DATUM_JUL)  PMON                                           
                               FROM                                                                  
                                 D$DW7305.W73RKALW                                                   
                               WHERE                                                                 
                                 KALW_PMON = '+00'                                                   

                              )                                                                      
                      AND  SUBSTR(AUFT_PAT, 1, 4) YEAR = YEAR(CURRENT DATE) CURRENTYEAR              
                      AND  MONTH(CURRENT DATE) CURRENTMONTH > 1                                      
                        )                                                                            
                      OR                                                                             
                           (                                                                         
                           YEAR = CURRENTYEAR - 1                                                    
                      AND  CURRENTMONTH = 1                                                          
                           )                                                      
OUT DBIN010
OUT DBIN020
OUT DBIN030
OUT DBIN040
OUT DBIN050
OUT DBIN060
OUT ZWAA071
OUT ZWAA090
OUT ZWAA150
OUT ZWAA200
```

Comment: You write "mainframe" , do you mean "Db2 for Z/OS" or "Db2 for i" ?  Do you know which indexes exist on which of the tables in the query? Do you know how to view the  access-plan for your query?

Comment: Sorry, I mean DB2 for Z/OS. No I don't, all the information I have about this table is the query. No I don't, could you tell me?

Comment: Query SYSIBM.SYSINDEXES to learn which indexes exist . If you use IBM-Data-Studio as your client-tooling it has built-in tools for optimizing queries, showing you the access plans etc.  Speak with more experienced people at your site who will show you how query analysis is done with which tools at your site.  There's many ways to write your SQL query, but unless you know which indexes exist and how to examine the access-plans then you won't know which is best.